# The Hammerpede scene -- what was the purpose of going into Millburn's throat?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

Of course, knowing what we do now of facehuggers and also the Engineer and the giant octopus, we might assume it intended to impregnate Millburn but as far as I know, it just kills him while his buddy gets mutated. Is there a deleted scene that indicates or does the novelization indicate something further happens to Millburn? It is not clear to me what causes the other guy's mutation since all that happens to him is that he is sprayed with acid -- there does not seem to be direct contact with the hammerpede in his case.

Comment: Good luck referencing the novelisation. You'll need to speak Japanese

Comment: i am unaware of the entirety of canon. i guess there are literally dozens of graphic novels also. do u agree the scene and what happens to the geologist are both confusing?

Comment: The film did not receive a graphic novelisation.

Comment: i am thinking that they intended Millburn to be the mutant. That would have made much more sense. Or just something should happen with the hammerpede besides it choking him, right?

Comment: @releasabe - The film was shredded in the edit. Trying to puzzle out what bit was supposed to go where is not an easy task

Comment: ok. i never liked the millburn character much anyway.

Comment: Fifield was likely mutated by the black goo, which was all over the floor. He fell face first into it right after his helmet was sprayed with the acidic blood from the Hammerpede. Incidentally, there were worms on the floor in that chamber before the black goo leaked out of the vases, so they were likely mutated into the Hammerpedes. As for Milburn, [the screenplay](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Prometheus.html) seems to indicate that he was just dead. No more to it than that.

Comment: @LogicDictates: Then Millburn got off easy. Yeah, no five second rule with black goo and he was on the floor a lot longer than five seconds anyway.

Comment: The black goo wasn't covering the entire floor. There were rivers of it, and a big puddle near the centre of the room. Fifield fell face first into the puddle, while Milburn's corpse was found on what appeared to be a dry patch of the floor.

Comment: @LogicDictates: Millburn had the hammerpede inside his body. something should have happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Prometheus.html) early draft of the script indicates that Milburn was simply killed by the Hammerpede (or centipede, as it's referred to in this version of the script). There's no indication that there was any other reason for the creature going inside him.

> INT. CATACOMBS - INSECT CHAMBER
>
> Milburn writhes on the ground, heels drumming frantically against the deck. Excruciating screams.
>
> Fifield kneels over him, helplessly pulling at the tail of the centipede - which has all but vanished into Milburn's suit. A trickle of scarlet from the hole.
>
> Fifield is delirious with horror. He clutches at the centipede in vain. It slips through his gloves.
>
> Milburn claws at Fifield, wild-eyed.
>
> MILBURN: Cut off my arm. Cut off my -
>
> He convulses. Spits blood. The head of the centipede emerges between his teeth. **He seizes. Choking and dying.**
>
> FIFIELD: Jesus Christ!
>
> He leaps up. Backs away. Runs into the dark.
>
> <sub>*Prometheus* script (early draft)</sub>

When the rest of the crew discovers Milburn's body, it's explicitly stated that he's dead.

> CATACOMBS - MILBURN'S RESTING PLACE
>
> Janek and Stillwell stand aghast. Their flashlights illuminate a hideous sight:
>
> **Milburn lies dead on the deck.** His body contorted in agony. His head inside his helmet is gnawed down to the bone.
>
> <sub>*Prometheus* script (early draft)</sub>

As for Fifield, in this version of the script, he doesn't get sprayed by the centipede's blood, and runs off instead. He then stops to rest in another room, and ends up getting bitten on the cheek by a flying insect, which was presumably mutated by the black goo. The bite transmits foreign DNA into his bloodstream, which causes his transformation.

> INT. CATACOMBS - LONELY PASSAGE - NIGHT
>
> Fifield stumbles along. Exhausted. Pouring sweat inside his suit. He is hopelessly lost. He slams into a resinous structure that topples to the floor. Things break.
>
> He whips his light around in jittery paranoia. Taps at his comm controls, getting only static.
>
> In Fifield's headlamp beam, the blackness is filling with motes of light. A blizzard of tiny flying insects.
>
> SCARABS.
>
> FIFIELD: Fifield to Magellan. Come on, come on. Anybody, seriously! God damn it!
>
> Scarabs flit through the darkness around him. They alight on his shoulders. Crawl over his visor. Obscuring his vision.
>
> FIFIELD: Get off!
>
> He swats at his visor, killing some. The crushed insects produce acid that eats into the plexiglass in seconds.
>
> FIFIELD: Shit.
>
> He twists, craning with his flashlight to inspect himself. Brushes scarabs away right and left.
>
> Acid opens a hole in his visor. Scarabs are inside. Buzzing around his head. Fifield freaks out, clawing at his helmet.
>
> **A scarab bites his cheek.**
>
> FLASH ON:
>
> **The microscopic world - as strange DNA invades Fifield's bloodstream. Virulent strands of protein attack the native DNA, transforming...**
>
> FIFIELD
>
> As his pupils dilate, breath hissing into his nostrils. His expanding body stiffens as if shocked by a powerful electric current. He screams. Falls, convulsing.
>
> <sub>*Prometheus* script (early draft)</sub>

Within the actual film, Fifield instead falls face first into a puddle of the black goo, right after his helmet is sprayed with the acidic blood from the Hammerpede. He then lifts his head up, and the front part of his helmet collapses onto his face with the black goo all over it.

Comment: wow. this reminds me of the possibility that just breathing the air might be a way to get infected as sort of almost happened in Covenant. perhaps a xenomorph sheds viruses or some microorganism that if not mutating people are inimical in other horrible ways. i just personally feel that xenomorphs and black goo are far too dangerous for humans to consider using for any reason and attempts to research them for even "good" reasons will almost inevitably end badly. It is like the smallpox virus squared -- we are not smart enough to handle it.